# Minkowski bound of $229$-th cyclotomic field

Tags: elementary-number-theory, class-field-theory, cyclotomic-fields

If $K = \mathbb{Q}\zeta_{229}$, the $229$-th cyclotomic field, Wwat is a good approximation for the bound $n$ such that every class in the ideal class group of $K$ contains an integral ideal of norm $p < n$. Without any calculation necessary, prove that $n < 2^{(229-1)/2}$.

Comment: Why not to use Minkowski's bound?

Comment: I am always confused as to weather the $\sqrt D$ part is in there (I.e. the square root of field discriminant) Wikipedia says it's part of the formula for the bound, planet math says it's not, different formulas from other sources etc.

Comment: Look up the word "book" on the internet.